# Could uninstalling Matlab 2020b and matlab2021a affect my programming?

Tags: python, uninstall, disk-usage, matlab

I'm trying to free up space on my Linux. Looking for what was taking up disc space I noticed that Matlab 2020b and matlab2021a are taking a significant amount of disc space (ca 60 GB). I do not use Matlab at all when i program. I use Python via VScode with som modules that utilize fortran programs. Could uninstalling Matlab affect my Python programming? If not, how do i uninstall the two matlab versions?

Comment: Hello. Couple of things first what is tyhe actual version of Ubuntu that you are using? Second how were the programs installed? Were they apt get, flatpak or snap or something else? To remove them you need to know how they were installed.

Comment: Version: 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver). I got the computer through my university with matlab already installed so I'm not certain how it was installed. Is there any way to determine this?

Comment: Matlab is proprietary software, so it is unlikely it would come with the standard Ubuntu software center. Removing requires knowing where the files are installed, and you will not easily be able to install the software yourself, unless you have the installer (if any).

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling Matlab will not affect your Python programming in any way.

How to remove Matlab is a different matter. In general, adding and removing software in Ubuntu is easy and safe using the Software center. Matlab, however, is a proprietary program. Installation on linux systems out of the regular package management system of the distribution can proceed in different and specific ways. There is no command to determine this. You will need to consult the documentation of that particular program to learn how it is installed, and how it can be correctly removed. The hard way to 'uninstall' is manually try to find out what directories and files have been installed by the program on the system, and remove these, but this can be risky.